# objc_getClass: load swift class inheriting NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to dynamically load a Swift class inheriting from `NSObject` using the objc runtime. (I'm trying to load the class from ObjC, not from Swift)

My Swift class:

```
@objc public class TestClass : NSObject {

    @objc public func testMethod() -> String {
        return "String"
    }

}
```

According to Apple's documentation,

> The `@objc` attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C and the Objective-C runtime

But the result of `objc_getClass("TestClass")` is `(null)`.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not possible at all to load swift classes inheriting an ObjC class using the objc runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify an Objective-C name for your class, not just include `@objc`:

```
@objc(TestClass) public class TestClass : NSObject {

    @objc public func testMethod() -> String {
        return "String"
    }

}

NSClassFromString("TestClass") // TestClass.Type

objc_getClass("TestClass") // TestClass
```

Otherwise your class will not be registered with the Objective-C runtime, and calls like `objc_getClass` or `NSClassFromString` will return `nil`.

Comment: Actually if you do a `print(TestClass.className())` (without specifying an Objective-C name), it'll output "objc_class_name.TestClass" – which you can use with `objc_getClass`. So it is registered with the runtime, it just has a prefixed name.

Comment: @Hamish ooh I didn't know that.  Thanks!  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Hamish Hmm, `TestClass.className()` does not compile for me (Swift 3).

Comment: And `objc_getClass("objc_class_name.TestClass")` returns `nil`.

Comment: Huh, weird (works fine for me in Swift 3!). Try `print(NSStringFromClass(TestClass.self))` instead

Comment: `print(NSStringFromClass(TestClass.self))` -> `__lldb_expr_74.TestClass`

Comment: I'm targeting iOS if that matters.

Comment: Ah, that could be it – I'm targeting OSX. Interesting. I bet `objc_getClass("__lldb_expr_74.TestClass")` works though :)

Comment: It does!  Fascinating.

Comment: And yeah, `className()` looks like it comes as an extension of `NSObject`, provided by [`NSScriptClassDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsscriptclassdescription), which is only available for OSX. Interesting that the prefix differs depending on the target though (and probably other factors by the looks of the prefix generated for iOS), although of course doesn't change the answer that you should specify the name anyway!

Comment: Huh, when I try to run it on iOS, I'm getting a name of `objective_c_class_name.TestClass`. I really have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try `objc_getClass("YourAppName.TestClass")`? Most likely the module name is prepended. You can verify the exact name which is used behind the scenes by using `NSStringFromClass([TestClass class])`

Comment: A namespace collision isn't the issue in this particular case, but good guess.